# Post Testflight Execution in Xcode Cloud

Tags: xcode-cloud

Is there a way to execute code after the app has been uploaded successfully to Testflight?

I am trying to post the patch notes of the update into Slack. I would be fine if there is a way to put the patch notes into the "What's New" section for the app in Testflight instead.

The current Slack integration seems to show the Git title rather than the title/summary + the description. I would love to use either the last commit's description or a separate file in my repo to host all the changes.

Comment: I would also like to be able to set the What To Test in TestFlight with a list of recent commits.

Comment: I ended up using fastlane. I did see something in WWDC 2023 that said something along the lines of adding a file to Xcode with the update changes (similar to a plist file) and it would automatically show for Testflight users.